# Typescript infering type from Generic

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function that takes a Generic and if the parameter is of type string, trim the value and return it, otherwise return the value.

I made this

```
export function trimString<T>(u: T) {
  if (typeof u === 'string') {
    return u.trim();
  }
  return u;
}
const a = trimString(12); // string | 12
const b = trimString('12'); // string

const c = trimString(Number(12)); // string | number
```

The issue is a and c are not infered correctly.

I tried also this which gives me better types but a TSError in the type guard

```
export function trimString<T>(u: T): T {
  if (typeof u === 'string') {
    return u.trim(); // TS2322: Type  string  is not assignable to type  T 
  }
  return u;
}
const a = trimString(12); // 12
const b = trimString('12'); // '12'

const c = trimString(Number(12)); // number
```

I made a [link to easily reproduce the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVxlTAWwGV9MUBzAHgBUA+ACiQC44aBKVmuAbwCg4cTAjgMYATzDAIIpHAC8iuAHIAzmUrL2vAYLhRgMJFFxIAdGUIN2Abl0BfXQaMm4SO47Q51cAIYK8AhINCgYARgAmWz4vFB8AIwDLUgJKBmVIrTsY73g0JKCU8lCAOSRCeOAocKjooA)

How can I solve this?

Comment: The types `string | 12` and `string | number` are indeed correct, just not as specific as you like.  Your change makes `trimString(' 12 ')` return type `' 12 '` which is actually incorrect.   TS is not clever enough to figure out what you're trying to do here so you'd have to tell it explicitly and assert that the implementation is correct, maybe like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKKMMW) shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It does thank you and you are making a good point about the type and trimming issue

Comment: The problem here is that if your generic type is a child of (extending) String, then trimming it will lose the additional information. So you need to do as jcalz says and tell TS: "if T is a child of string, then it will return a simple string". Look at SuperString here: https://tsplay.dev/WJ1Mlm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original function had the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature `<T>(u: T) => string | T`.  This type is *correct*, in the sense that no matter what type `T` you pass in for `u`, the output will either be of type `string` or of type `T`.  Your problem is that it's not *specific* enough; you want the compiler to understand that if `u` is not a string, then the output is the same type as the input.

Your change has the call signature `<T>(u: T) => T`, which is *incorrect*.  The function will [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) any string input.  This has the possibility of changing the output.  For example, if `u` is a string of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `" 12 "` then the function will output `"12"`.  But the signature `<T>(u: T) => T` implies it will be `" 12 "`, which is incorrect.  The reason you get the error is because the compiler cannot verify that `u.trim()` will be of type `T`, and it's a good reason.  Sometimes it will not be.

---

You can write a more accurate call signature like

```
<T>(u: T) => T extends string ? string : T
```

The return type is [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). So `trimString(12)` will be `12` because `T extends string` is false, but `trimString("12")` will be `string` because `T extends string` is true.  You can even try to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to represent what happens to string literal types, so that the output is more specific than `string`:

```
<T>(u: T) => T extends string ? Trim<T> : T;
```

where `Trim<T>` is a custom utility type like

```
type Trim<T extends string> =
  T extends `${Whitespace}${infer R}` ? Trim<R> :
  T extends `${infer R}${Whitespace}` ? Trim<R> :
  T;

type Whitespace = 
  "\t" | "\v" | "\f" | " " | "\n" | "\r" | "\u2028" | "\u2029" | "\u00a0" | "\ufeff"
```

That definition isn't perfect, but it's probably pretty close. There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#41283](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41283) to introduce a *built-in* `Trim<T>`, but for now there's no such thing, so you'd have to build it yourself.

Now `trimString(" 12 ")` would return `"12"`.   This might be overkill for your needs, not sure:

```
const a = trimString(12);
// const a: 12
const b = trimString("12");
// const b: "12"
const c = trimString(Number(12));
// const c: number
const d = trimString(" 12 ");
// const d: "12"
const e = trimString(`
    Hello there, how are you?
`);
//const e: "Hello there, how are you?"
```

---

Unfortunately one you have a generic conditional type like this, there's no way for the compiler to verify that the return value is correct.  It just can't follow the logic to connect `if (typeof u === string) return y; else return n;` to `T extends string ? Y : N`.  There's an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) asking for this, but for now it's not part of the language.

Meaning if you want your function to return a generic conditional type, you'll need to loosen the type checking via [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or something similar.  You can write the function body and prevent compiler errors, but *you* have to verify its correctness; the compiler currently cannot.

So you can use type assertions:

```
function trimStringA<T>(u: T): T extends string ? Trim<T> : T {
  if (typeof u === 'string') {
    return u.trim() as T extends string ? Trim<T> : T;
  }
  return u as T extends string ? Trim<T> : T;
}
```

or it's often easier to use a single call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), since overloaded function implementations are checked loosely by the compiler:

```
// call signature
function trimString<T>(u: T): T extends string ? Trim<T> : T;

// implementation, checked loosely
function trimString(u: unknown) {
  if (typeof u === 'string') {
    return u.trim();
  }
  return u;
}
```

---

Oh, and speaking of overloads, that's another approach you can take to having a function that returns different types based on different ways of calling it, instead of using conditional types.  In this case you want to either support a string or some other type, so you can write it with two call signatures:

```
function trimString<T extends string>(u: T): Trim<T>;
function trimString<T>(u: T): T;
function trimString(u: unknown) {
  if (typeof u === 'string') {
    return u.trim();
  }
  return u;
}
```

or even just

```
function trimString(u: string): string;
function trimString<T>(u: T): T;
function trimString(u: unknown) {
  if (typeof u === 'string') {
    return u.trim();
  }
  return u;
}
```

if you don't need string literal output types.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gFgS2BAzmAhgY2gXigIgB1h8oAfAwgN1IqIDNaDm7CA7JogJ08IFcATAAYBADl6CRATglCh6IRPoR6jAFChIUACpcEAWwA82qBAAeyNgBMUUFMD1sA5gD4oONVB2mLEa7YADABIAb3gkVAxsAF9QhDZlLigAJWiAqAB+HT0jZLcALk9vc0sbKGCQ+MSU2LDEZDQsCDTM7INDPKhCr20AbjU1ej42TGAEAHs2KAcDAGUZ5wBBYxcACj58nQBKTZMSvzL7RydW3XbtAu8QooR6KFXNCHG7vnccPAByI-inD62oa5eLxcCDAPhcKZ8AB0M30q3+6Fse18-jsCxOWTORguXR0-S80SKILBEKgr0RxRRh3RpxyK1xfTUhIGQxGY0m0xy82OK3Wux2lNKtm+zlp50ujNZowmU1h3J+fLJbAA1mxxgB3Nj-QFQW73R7PMlvT4i37aorA0HgyEwnLw-FQQmWkmQ-qEzCTexQdDuTlzdGrACMAi2-QA9GGoB62F70Jtg2po16AEa+uUB-DB-ChtQRqOe4BQZObTMCfCJgtRtNcgMAOT4+mTEC4QZDObzScLmE2bAbTa4FZjhas1f9x1WpGDBHbkc7UCsJazg69uD9+nlzlWAQtUAAEhAADYH8bTODNiAAGigcA13pBUBA4z4GTUARnc4gJf3R5PwDPIKvG91TvaBH2fcs1DYdB9EiJodHVcYAGF0CPWYECcWxrgGLwpXZWUax5ZEhTRY41g2bZdjpC4HVwmU1w3JxeXI7QBUZHDhmlDl03HcjhlVDUtQBHc9QecAnheY0oC+dE-iEoEgWJa0yVtAx7R3J0FKtUk+AdZkvDnH08G4hVgxzLwO0rOMoATfTK1TIyCIVUtswdCyhyLRcyyKOdMFHdc6z7ZtWy2MyoDcr1uygXtG2bbzKxHByxyc6yBGnVzZ3izzy1s9zV2Mzdt3k79j1Pc9ANvdB7zAl833Sj8v0PEq-zK68Kqqp8Mgg9i2To-KnAABUVU0BVNGiOLw+j0X6pj+V2Maeq4xznEG3iVTVTVzXkkSDQk94TRkzb5KgRTtJUuFQoJHcTtdIpmSZIA)

Comment: Amazing explanation, thank you!